# How to run Blackberry Desktop Software?

Tags: 12.10, wine, blackberry

I need Blackberry Desktop Software because my pics are encrypted and my computer can't read them, and looks like that program is the only way to decrypt them. But I can't execute the program on Wine.

For example I try to update and

```
[POL_System_CheckFS] Message: Checking filesystem for /home/xxxxxx/.win/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Research In Motion/BlackBerry Desktop/Rim.Desktop.AutoUpdate.exe
[POL_Wine] Message: Running wine- /home/xxxxxx/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files/Research In Motion/BlackBerry Desktop/Rim.Desktop.AutoUpdate.exe 
[POL_Wine] Message: Notice: PlayOnLinux deliberately disables winemenubuilder. See http://www.playonlinux.com/fr/page-26-Winemenubuilder.html
The entry point method could not be loaded
[POL_Wine] Error: Wine seems to have crashed

If your program is running, just ignore this message
[POL_Wine] Message: Wine return: 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"configSections" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"section" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"log4net" in state 1
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"appender" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"file" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"appendToFile" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"maximumFileSize" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"maxSizeRollBackups" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"rollingStyle" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"datePattern" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"layout" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"header" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"conversionPattern" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"logger" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"level" in state 3
fixme:mscoree:ConfigFileHandler_startElement Unknown element L"appender-ref" in state 3
```

Please I need help. Just tell me if I need to post more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should [check the WineHQ AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6537) before assuming software works.

Assuming we're talking about the same application, the Blackberry Desktop Software, the application is listed as "Garbage" on all versions of Wine with a lot of versions of the software, which means it has very little success of running in Wine.

The best you could do is get a Windows 7 VM and not activate Windows, and hope that it works from the VM, or in a worst-case scenario, install Windows alongside Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Some people have reported that BlackBerry Desktop Manager **does** work on Wine.

Install PlayOnLinux: `sudo apt-get install playonlinux`

Open it up and press Install.

[image]

Press "Install non-listed program" at bottom left of the Install window.

[image]

Configure your virtual drive. Untick the three "Wine prefix" boxes, and use 32-bit WIndows installation to play safe (fear not, your 64-bit pc can also run 32-bit.)

[image]
[image]

When prompted, browse to the BB Desktop Manager Setup and install. Ignore errors for now. If PlayOnLinux shows some error, just press Next and Wine will fix it up.

Make a shortcut for it and finish the wizard. Now, in the PlayOnLinux general window, click "Configure."

[image]

Select your BB Desktop Manager drive on the list on the left, Go to the "Install Components" tab and install dotnet35 and dotnet35sp1. And once done, try to run your Desktop Manager again. It should work now ;)

**If it doesn't work still:** Install dotnet4 and try again.

**Yet it's an epic fail:** Download VirtualBox: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox`

Create a new Virtual Machine in it and install a copy of Windows 7. Then you can run BB Desktop Manager in it and it shall truly work, provided there is no problem with the USB interface.

Please mark as answer if this works so that others can use this knowledge too.

Comment: I can't pick 32 or 64 bits I can't only pick System on that step

Comment: 1. Use 32 bits to play safe
2. Yes, select System :)

Comment: There is not step here to pick 32 or 64 bits

Comment: Continue as normal.